# Magento: Filter products by Status

Tags: php, magento, filter, collections, status

I'm having some serious Magento issues here. As expected the following:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
```

Will return all enabled products for my $category_id. However this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 0));
```

Does not return disabled products. I can't seem to find a way to return disabled products, and I don't know why.

I've tried this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
```

Which was meant to have worked, but apparently may have been deprecated.

Does anyone know how to get all products in a category, enabled and disabled?

Comment: If you are using flat catalog, you won't be able to return disabled products as flat catalog gathers only enabled products.

Comment: I see, is there any way round this?

Edit: Looking in my settings, both Use Flat Catalog Product and Use Flat Catalog Category, are set to no. Does this mean I'm not using a flat catalog?

Comment: Indeed, it means that you are not using flat catalog...

Comment: So technically then, I should be able to return disabled products!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Don't worry, you simply got trapped by a very unusual constant definition^^. Just try:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
);
```

For whatever reasons Varien decided to define this `STATUS_DISABLED` constant with a value of `2`, instead of the more intuitive (and commonly used) value of `0`.

Comment: Great answer! I don't have time to test it as it stands, but you seem to know it'll work. I'll mark it as correct and test it later!

Comment: Lifesaver! Disabled=2. Who'd have thunk it.

Comment: Actually.... this will only work if you are not using flat tables. Disabled products are not included in the flat tables, and so cannot be retrieved from a product collection.

Comment: @Benubird: apart from that the system of the OP uses EAV (not flat), you're wrong in the main point, anyway. You're right, that a flat product table doesn't contain disabled products. But you're wrong, when saying disabled products could not be retrieved from a product collection when flat products are enabled. You can. Just use the admin store.

Comment: @JürgenThelen I just checked again, and you're right. I remember looking at a definition of getProductCollection that used flat tables for the admin, but now I can't find it; I must have been reading it wrong to begin with. Still think it's worth noting though, as if you want to filter by status and store (which is implied), it becomes more complicated. And you haven't included setStore() in the answer.

Comment: Just to add; The status is probably not 0 since its a key somewhere? You don't want to start your keys with a 0, in that case it makes sense.

Comment: Flat Tables are only used for the frontend AND only if the flat tables are enabled in System Configuration (which I believe they are by default). MAJOR NOTE: if you are loading the collection in order to edit the product data in any way (like an import), you will have major problems and unexpected behavior unless you switch to the Admin store... Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::app()->getStore(0));

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this by setting store to default like

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

make sure you save the current store value and set it back after doing the above.

Or by using a script from outside magento and invoke mage by

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app();
Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) 
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) 
        ->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
```

Comment: How to add filter status, created_at, entity_name for -> $order->getStatusHistoryCollection()->getData(); @Hassan Ali Shahzad

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an answer as such to my question above. But I have saved a lot of time by using a different method.

I exported a CSV of all the products in my Magento, deleted all columns except Category ID and SKU (this is all I needed), and then filtered that to return all the skus instead.

If it helps anyone here is the code -

```
<?php
$file  = fopen('allprods.csv', 'r');

// You can use an array to store your search ids, makes things more flexible.
// Supports any number of search ids.
$id = array($_GET['id']);    
// Make the search ids safe to use in regex (escapes special characters)
$id = array_map('preg_quote', $id);
// The argument becomes '/id/i', which means 'id, case-insensitive'
$regex = '/'.implode('|', $id).'/i';

$skus = array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
    list($ids, $sku) = $line;

    if(preg_match($regex, $ids)) {
        $skus[] = $sku;
    }
}

$count = count($skus);
$i = 1;

echo $category_id;
foreach ($skus as $sku){
    echo $sku;
    if($i != $count) { echo "`"; }
    $i++;
}
```

This solution was created by using a previous topic about filtering CSVs, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382678/filter-a-csv-file-by-a-word-or-text-using-php)

So for now, I can survive. however - an answer to this question is still needed!

Comment: The default behavior of `preg_quote()` does not escape forward slashes (which you have used as your pattern delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works if `catalog_flat_product` is on in backend configuration->catalog.

try this..this will give all the products enabled and disabled ultimately

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'); //this will give you all products
foreach($collection as $col)
{
$var = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$col->getSku());
echo"<pre>";print_r($var->getData());echo"</pre>";
}
```

its really simple and after this you can easily filter products by status