# preg_match exact number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using

```
$regex = '/'.implode('|', 10).'/i';    
preg_match($regex, $ids)
```

to find the number 10 in a list of IDs ($ids). However, if the list of IDs looks like this:

```
$ids = array(10, 110, 1010);
```

Would it bring back all of them? How can I make it find the exact number I am after, and not just find a number that *contains* the number I'm after?

Thanks.

Edit:

I made a mistake above. The list of IDs is actually a string of comma separated values. For example:

```
$ids = "10,1010,101";
```

It's hard to explain the whole idea process behind this, but this is my full code:

```
<?php
$file  = fopen('allprods.csv', 'r');


$id = array($_GET['id']);    
$id = array_map('preg_quote', $id);
$regex = '/'.implode('|', $id).'/i';

$skus = array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
    list($ids, $sku) = $line;

    if(preg_match($regex, $ids)) {
    $skus[] = $sku;
    }
}

$count = count($skus);
$i = 1;

echo $category_id;
foreach ($skus as $sku){
        echo $sku;
        if($i != $count) { echo "`"; }
        $i++;
}
```

I'm essentially rooting through a csv that has an ID column (some rows have multiple ids in that column, spearated by commas), and an sku column. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651028/magento-filter-products-by-status)

So I need the code to check the string of ids for a certain ID, for example 10, and then add the appropriate SKU to an sku array.

I'm sure this code is a mess, so bear with me while I hack PHP to bits!

**Edit:** This is now solved! I used in_array instead, as mentioned in the answers. First of all I exploded the comma separate string. Code can be seen below:

```
$skus = array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
    list($ids, $sku) = $line;

    $cats = explode(',',$ids);

    if (in_array($_GET['id'], $cats)) {
        $skus[] = $sku;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help all.

Comment: why did not you use in_array( "10", array( ..... ) , true  ) ?

Comment: Sorry Guys, I have realised my question doesn't make a huge amount of sense out of context. Your answers may lead me to a solution. I will post a response shortly

Comment: you may want to consider using a mysql or similar database for this. much faster/easier.

Comment: Yes, you may be right there - I'll re-evaluate my idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a regex for this. Use `in_array()`

```
if( in_array(10, $ids) ) {
     // do something
}
else {
     // not found
}
```

Comment: Cheers, solution posted above

Answer (score 2):

In regex, if you want to find an exact match rather than just a substring match, you need to use start and end anchors. These are represented in regex by the `^` (start) and `$` (end) characters.

So your regex to find "10" and not "110", etc, would be `/^10$/`.

But if you're looking for a number, why not just use `==` or `in_array()`?

PHP is quite capable of evaluating a numeric without having to parse it with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$regex = '/^10$/';
```

this will only match if the ^ is the beginning of the string, and the $ is the end of the string.

Comment: I've realised this answer is correct for what I asked, however, I have updated my question with more info - as this will now work in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `in_array()` as suggested by @Cfreak, but if you want to use regex to match an id of `10` you can do

```
preg_match('/[^\d]?10[^\d]?/', implode('|', $ids))
```

If you have `array(1,10,1010,010)`, `implode()` will change this to `1|10|1010|010` and the pattern will match against '10' not preceded or followed by any other digit *(ie. another `0` or `1` as in `0101`)*