# Search for line in text file and display Yes or No PHP

Tags: php, string, search, text

Alright, so lets say you have a file name "search.txt" and the contents of that file is:

```
1223
1245
3389
4489
...
```

and when you're at index.php and you search for "1223", it will return TRUE, but if you search for "12" (which would come back true for 2 occasions because of the first and second line contain "12"), it would come back FALSE because it's not EXACTLY matching the full line.

This is what I have so far, but it's not working:

```
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $searchfile = file_get_contents('search.txt');

    if (preg_quote($searchfile, $uid) === false)
    {
       echo "NO";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "YES";
    }
```

Thank you for any response!

Comment: What gave you the idea `preg_quote` would search for strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653045/preg-match-exact-number does this help? Pass the file to an array and search the array (basically).

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure whether the numbers are separated by line or by space, but if it's by newline then the following one liner should work:

```
if(array_search($uid, file('search.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)) === false) {
   echo 'no';
} else {
   echo 'yes';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file doesn't get too big, you could loop through each line with the `file()` function:

```
$lines = file('search.txt');
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$found = false;

foreach ($lines as $line){
    if ($line == $uid)
        $found = true;
}

if ($found)
    echo 'YES';
else
    echo 'NO';
```